# JQgrid Navigation is displaced

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

as my topic says, my problem is that my JQgrid Navigation is displaced to the bottom. I can see just the half of the navigation.

My code to implement the Table is correct, all stuff is working fine unless this thing, so what is the problem that i have to change?
This is my relevant code snippet...Thanks

```
$("#userEingetragen").jqGrid(
                {

                    url : "BenutzerLaden",
                    datatype : "json",
                    mtype : "POST",
                    width : "auto", 
                    height : "auto",    
                    colNames : [ "Id", "Vorname", "Nachname", "Geschlecht",
                            "EMail", "Benutzername", "Firma"],
                    colModel : [
                            {
                                name : "id",
                                width : 15,
                                key : true,
                                hidden:true

                            },
                            {
                                name : "vorname",
                                width : 150,
                                editable : true

                            },
                            {
                                name : "nachname",
                                width : 150,
                                align : "left",
                                editable : true

                            },
                            {
                                name : "geschlecht",
                                width : 80,
                                align : "center",
                                editable : true,
                                edittype : "select",
                                editoptions : {
                                    value : "männlich:männlich;weiblich:weiblich"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                name : "email",
                                width : 250,
                                align : "left",
                                editable : true

                            },
                            {
                                name : "benutzername",
                                width : 150,
                                align : "left",
                                editable : true,

                            },
                            {
                                label: "Firma",
                                name : "firma",
                                width : 150,
                                align : "left",
                                editable : true,
                                edittype : "text",
                                editoptions:{dataInit: function (element) {
                                window.setTimeout(function () {
                                        $(element).autocomplete({

                                            id: 'AutoComplete',
                                            source: function(request, response){
                                            this.xhr = $.ajax({
                                                url: "Factorys",
                                                data: request,
                                                dataType: "json",
                                                success: function( data ) {
                                                    response( data );
                                                },
                                                error: function(model, response, options) {
                                                    response([]);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        },
                                        autoFocus: true,
                                        highlight: true,
                                        minLength: 2,
                                        cacheLength: 2

                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }],

                    pager : "#jqGridPager",
                    rowNum : 5,
                    rowList : [ 5, 15, 20 ],
                    sortname : "id",
                    sortorder : "asc",
                    viewrecords : true,
                    gridview : true,
                    caption : "Benutzer",
                    onSelectRow : function(id) {
                        var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id);
                        cellId = rowData["id"];


                    },
                    groupingView : {
                        groupField : [ "id" ],
                        groupColumnShow : [ true ],
                        groupText : [ "<b>{0}</b>" ],
                        groupOrder : [ "asc" ],
                        groupSummary : [ false ],
                        groupCollapse : false

                    }
                }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#jqGridPager", {
            edit : true,
            add : true,
            del : true,

        },
        // BEARBEITEN OPTIONEN
        {
            url : "ChangeCustomers",
            closeAfterEdit : true,
            onclickSubmit : function(options, postData) {
                return {
                    customerID : cellId
                };
            },
            zIndex:3000
        },

        // HINZUFÜGEN OPTIONEN
        {
            url : "AddCustomers",
            closeAfterAdd : true,
            zIndex:3000
        },
        // LÖSCHEN OPTIONEN
        {
            url : "DeleteCustomers",
            closeAfterDel : true,
            onclickSubmit : function(options, postData) {
                var val = $("#userEingetragen").getCell(postData, "id");
                return {list_id:val};

            },
            zIndex:3000
        },
        {
            closeOnEscape : true,
            closeAfterSearch : true,
            ignoreCase : true,
            multipleSearch : true,
            sopt : [ "cn", "eq" ],
            defaultSearch : "cn"
        });
```

**EDIT**

So here is a picture of the problem. As you can see, the bottom is slipping away.

[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshort which show which problem exactly you have with navigator bar? The statement "Navigation is displaced to the bottom" is not clear enough. Are grid is inside of some other dialogs? Which version of jqGrid/free jqGrid/Guriddo jqGrid JS you use? Could you provide the demo which reproduce the problem?

Comment: No one has an answer?

Comment: I asked you many questions, but you included only one screenshort. It seems that the width (or some other CSS property) of the middle part of the pager is wrong. The reason could be a conflict with other CSS. The calculation of the width is different in different versions of jqGrid, so my question about the version of jqGrid/free jqGrid/Guriddo jqGrid JS is really mandatory. **I recommend you to change URLs to jqGrid files and to verify whether the problem exist in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)**.

Comment: @Oleg you'are right. The Problem was, that there was a conflict with my main CSS-Style Guide. Now it works - THANKS